# Update TextView from another Activity

Tags: java, android

I have two Activities in one application.

First one updates its TextViews every 3 seconds. It works fine.

When the keyguard (lock screen) is activated the first activity launches the second activity which appears over the lock screen (in order to show data even if the screen is locked). It also works fine.

I would like the TextViews of the second activity to be updated periodically by the first activity. I have played hours with this and tried a lot of suggestions I found with Google but none of them worked for me. The second activity always crashes with NullPointerException at the moment when the TextView.setText() is called.

What is the best practice for doing this?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: or you can use event bus (Green Robot), need to register for the event in first Activity and get the call back in second Activity to update there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a good way to do this, as your first activity could get collected by the system, and you generally don't want to do work after onPause has been called.

I would move that logic that updates the views into a service that runs in the background. Since it sounds like you only need this service while the application is running I would create a bound one.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: We can always create and interface on the second activity/first activity to communicate between those two activities. Yes, we can always use a service for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data on calling another activity as :

```
Intent intent =new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putStringExtra("TextName","Value");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: He is saying, he want to update second actvity textview from first activity which he can do passing the value, both activity cannot be visible at the same time , so mean time he can pass the value and update the textview

Comment: Just because both activities can't be visible at the same time that doesn't mean that the first one isn't on memory. You're just creating a new one here.

Answer (score 0):

As Ashish said you could use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus).

Add the library to your app and in your Second Activity register your activity in the EventBus in onCreate method:

```
EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
```

Create a new class in your project to define an event type:

```
public class TestEvent {
     public TestEvent() {}
}
```

So in your second activity create a method to receive the event:

```
public void onEvent(TestEvent event) {
  //stuff to do
}
```

Now, in your first activity you just have to "fire" the event in the method executed each 2 seconds:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new TestEvent());
```

Each time you execute post method, the onEvent of your second activity will be run.

Answer (score -1):

A way to do it is by defining a Singleton object that holds the value to be displayed on the TextView, for instance, a Integer or a String.

Both activities have access to read/write into this object. So when you come back to the second activity, maybe on the onResume() method..you can the following:

```
public void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   textview.setText(""+ MySingleton.getInstance().getValue());
}
```

On the other activity:

```
 public void updateMethod() {
    int newValue = .....;
    MySingleton.getInstance().setValue(newValue);
 }
```

This will make sure that whenever you come back to this activity (as onResume() is called), the value will be updated into the TextView. Of course, assuming that you are updating the value from the other activity accordingly.

Note this is the simplest solution you can do, professionally, I would do an *event driven* solution, where the observer gets notified when the value is changed. For that you can play with http://square.github.io/otto/ library.